Actualizar Conexiones y consultas con un boton usando Macros VBA Excel
Hola buenas tardestexto destacado,
Tengo varios libros con varias tablas dinámica y varias conexiones en diferentes hojas. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es actualizar por separado las tablas dinámicas y las conexiones externas. Para esto ya conseguí un código que me actualiza solo las tablas dinámicas:
'Declaramos variables
Dim Hoja As Worksheet
Dim TD As PivotTable

'Recorremos cada hojas del archivo
For Each Hoja In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    'Recorremos cada TD de cada hoja
    For Each TD In Hoja.PivotTables
        'Actualizar cada TD
        TD.RefreshTable
    Next TD
Next Hoja

Pero ahora me falta un código parecido que actualice solo las conexiones externas masivamente independiente de la cantidad y ubicación (hojas o libros) de dichas conexiones.
El botón "Actualizar Todo" del Excel no me sirve porque me actualiza también las tablas dinámicas.
Actualmente lo estoy manejando asi:
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Consulta - Sheet1").Refresh
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Consulta - Table 1").Refresh

Sin embargo, tengo diferentes libros con diferentes conexiones uno a uno, tendría que hacer varios botones para cada libro por las diferentes conexiones que existan. Mi objetivo es que con un solo botón pueda actualizar las conexiones de cualquier libro así como lo hago con las tablas dinámicas.
Gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Esto puede ayudarte:
Sub ActualizaConexiones()

    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        conn.Refresh
    Next conn

End Sub


Muchas Gracias. Funciona Perfecto.
